# How to write Capybara `visit` method with out capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write a spec for `omniauth` with `vcr` like this.

```
  describe "Omniauth" do
    describe "Twitter" do
      VCR.use_cassette 'omniauth/twitter' do
        auth = visit 'users/auth/twitter'
        auth.info.name.should exist
      end
    end
  end
```

This cause error `undefined method 'visit'`, and I found it is very tricky to use capybara and vcr at the same.

[vcr with capybara-webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214386/vcr-with-capybara-webkit)

So I'm going to write `visit` function without capybara.
But I don't know how to write it. Could anyone help me?

*Edit 2014/01/19*

This question is voted `closed` because my question was not clear, so I add more details.

`vcr` uses rack server and so is `capybara`, therefore normally I can't use Capybara's `visit` method inside of `VCR.use_cassette` method.

I want to know equivalent of `visit` method that is using only pure rspec method.

Comment: How about this article? http://betterspecs.org/#http

Comment: I think, the article explains how to use stub that is created already. But I want to create stub itself by using `vcr` in spec file. Thanks your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Rack::Test and its `#get` method. It's usually used with plain Rack apps like Sinatra, but it's also good for general API testing etc.

Here's a link to some steps to use it with Sinatra, the same applies for any Rack-based app though: http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html